# The order of $ab$ when $a,b$ commute?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Let $a$ and $b$ be two elements in a group with order $m$ and $n$ respectively.

If $ab=ba$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$, we have that the order of $ab$ is $mn$.

If we drop the condition that $\gcd(m,n)=1$, it's easy to get that the order of $ab$ is a divisor of $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$. Let the order of $ab$ be $d$, this is, $(ab)^d=a^db^d=1$. Then $a^d=b^{-d}$. The order of $a^d$ is $\frac{m}{\gcd(m,d)}$, and the order of $b^{-d}$ is $\frac{n}{\gcd(n,d)}$. So $$\frac{m}{\gcd(m,d)}=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,d)}.$$ You can see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1563981

My question: is the conditions are sufficient?

> Let $a$ and $b$ be two elements in a group with order $m$ and $n$ respectively $(m\ne n)$ and $ab=ba$. If a positive integer $d$ satisfy $$d\mid\operatorname{lcm}(m,n),\quad\frac{m}{\gcd(m,d)}=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,d)},$$
>   can we say that $d$ is the order of $ab$? If not, can you give an example and what information can we get furthermore for the order of $ab$?

---

Let $t=|a^{d}|=|b^{-d}|$. We have $a^d=b^{-d}\in<a>\cap<b>$, then $t|m$ and $t|n$. So $t|\gcd(m,n)$ and let $kt=\gcd(m,n)$. $a^{dt}=b^{-dt}=1$, then $m|dt$ and $n|dt$. So $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)|dt$, this is, $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)|d\frac{\gcd(m,n)}{t}$. So $$\frac{\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)}{\gcd(m,n)}\big{|}d.$$

Comment: Suppose $a$ has order $6$ and let $b=a^3$, so $b$ has order $2$.  the order of $ab=a^4=$ is $3$.  But taking $d=6$ we have $\frac 6{\gcd (6,6)}=1=\frac 2{\gcd (2,6)}$.

Comment: To phrase the example differently, it is easy to come up with commuting elements $a,b$ such that the order of $a$ is $6$, the order of $b$ is $2$ and the order of $ab$ is $6$ (look at permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ and say $a=(123456),b=(78)$).  Thus you really can't read the order of $ab$ off just from the sort of data your present.