# Give an example of commuting elements $x,y$ such that the order of $xy$ is not equal to the least common multiple of $|x|$ and $|y|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Assume $|x|=n$ and $|y|=m$ . Give  an  example  of  commuting elements  $x,y$  such that  the order  of  $xy$  is not equal to the least  common multiple  of $|x|$  and $|y|$

**My attempt** : I was thinking  about  taking the non-abelian Group $S_3$.Take  $x=(12)$and $y=(123)$ but here $xy \neq yx $ i,e $x$ and $y$ are   not commuting elements

After that  I'm thinking about again  abelian group $K_4$ where $K_4=\{1,x,y,xy\} $

Here $|x|=2$ and $|y|=2$ .So  $Lcm(x,y)=lcm(2,2)=2$  but $|x||y|=|xy|=2.2=4 $

I think in  $K_4$,  order  of  $xy$  is not equal to the least  common multiple  of $|x|$  and $|y|$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4229059/if-ab-ba-what-are-the-possible-orders-of-ab).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a non-identity $x$ and $y=x^{-1}$, then $|xy|=1 \neq lcm(|x|,|y|)=|x|$.

Comment: It's a beautiful example

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ be an element of order $2q$ in any group. Then $x\cdot x$ has order $q\neq\operatorname{lcm}(2q, 2q)=2q$.

Comment: I think $ x.x $  has  order $4q$

Comment: @jasmine Nope, order $q$. This follows from the fact that $(x^2)^q=x^{2q}=1$ so its order must divide $q$. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, so using additive notation, $1$ has order $4$, while $1+1=2$ has order $2$.